# How AdBlock Affects Web Testing

Tags: web-testing

Can anyone explain in detail how AdBlock would affect a website under test? My mentor advises disabling it before web testing, but I don’t understand why I would need to disable AdBlock.

Comment: In addition to @Rao's great answer, you should suggest testing with AdBlock enabled and disabled to see how it affects your website for different users - especially if it's responsive.

Comment: Most important question in this is: What part of the users of the website in production will be using AdBlock. Also good to know, what sort tests are you performing?

Answer (score 1):

Adblocker prevents some website traffic from reaching you.  Therefore, the behavior of the website you are testing may be different from if you were testing the website without adblocker.  If you wanted to test something as a user who was seeing the website for the first time, you should test it in incognito/private browsing mode without any extensions.